# SVG not use class colors?

Tags: html, css, svg, mixins

Problems changing the color of an SVG file that is being used.

I been trying to change an SVG file that I am using using CSS stylings, but cannot seem to make it work..

HTML:

```
<div class="svg--white" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;  position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 40%;">
<svg>
<use xlink:href="#public--play"></use>
</svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.svg{

    &--white {
      color: white;
      fill: white;
    }
}
```

The SVG keep be showing as white, eventhough the styling should mark it white.. Not sure I undestand how this is not working.

I can't seem to change the color in no way?

Comment: please make sure that `#public--play` has no `fill` attribute

Comment: It has one but it is null, and keeps coming everytime i compile?

Comment: `fill` is not valid css property for a HTML `div`, `background-color` is. Its valid for SVG nodes though, but `.svg--white` is not an SVG node

Answer (score 0):

You need some shapes in your SVG you can apply the `fill` to.

It is not a problem to give `fill` to a parent container of the SVG. Look at my example. Circles without a fill get blue filling, due to cascading nature of the style:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <svg class="example-svg" width='300px' height='300px'>
    <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='110'></circle>
    <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='90' fill="hsl(0, 100%, 50%)"></circle>
    <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='70' fill="hsl(20, 100%, 50%)"></circle>
    <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50' fill="hsl(40, 100%, 50%)"></circle>
    <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='30' fill="hsl(60, 100%, 50%)"></circle>
  </svg>
<section>
```